# Why doesn't the Ubuntu Installer see all of my hard drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup a dual boot system with Windows Vista 64 (already installed) and Ubuntu 10.10. I added a new drive which is identical to the one Vista is installed on. When I boot into the LiveCD I can see and mount the second drive and edit it in Gparted. However, when I use the installer it will only bring up the drive that already has Vista installed.

I've tried everything I know. I'm not sure if its a BIOS setting or something else I've missed.

Comment: This would be best on the [Ubuntu StackExchange](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks, http://askubuntu.com/questions/21267/why-doesnt-the-ubuntu-installer-see-all-of-my-hard-drives

Answer (score 0):

Have you clicked on the list box and selected the second drive? By default, the installer will show the partitions on the first drive.

Comment: Yes, I've tried all three install options and all three list the drive and partition where Vista is install, but does not list the second drive.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you have a newer motherboard the drivers for chipsets managing storage would be not included in Ubuntu LTS editions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot a live session and start a terminal session (or to switch to the console with CTRL-ALT-F1) and issue:

```
$ sudo os-prober
```

You'll probably see a probing error which could be the reason why your drive is not taken in consideration. It's quite likely that your second drive has leftovers of a RAID configuration, in this case it's sufficient to do:

```
$ sudo dmraid -rE
```

(-r = raid, -E remove metadata) and confirm the operation. Start the installer and you should see it.